# Enable BitCode error Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7-beta5

I have tried to compile my app with `Xcode 7 beta`, and i receive this error:

```
-U and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

if I disable it in the config settings all works fine, but it's fine to disable it? what I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcode is part of [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html), which will be a feature of iOS 9. Basically when you submit to Apple you are uploading the [intermediate representation of your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation). Apple then optimizes that for the devices on download.

It is fine to disable it, you just won't get the benefits of that feature. To disable it just go to the your project’s `Build Settings` in Xcode and search for `Bitcode`, and set it to False.

To quote from the [App Distribution Guide > App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2) page by Apple.

> **Bitcode (iOS, watchOS)**
>
> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.
>
> Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have already disable it, but if i enable it i receive that error, how i can use it without having the error?

Comment: Please update your question with a screen shot or copy of  any build warnings (or errors) when you build. It could be many things that it doesn't (current) like as it is in beta.

Answer (score 0):

First you have install Xcode 7 (GM). 
After the error occurs while updating the frameworks for giving the support to iOS9.

To change In build settings --> Enable Bitcode as "NO"

Not only for your project targets, to set all of your targets including your installed cocoapods(Project) targets.

Finally clean and build your project. Hope it will be fix!